# UIDocumentInteractionController not available in Mac catalyst

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, mac-catalyst, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

May app getting crash when execute below code.

**Code:**
`self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:targetURL];`

**Crash log:**
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController not available'

is there any solution for this issue or any alternative class?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not available in Catalyst, despite what the docs say.

You could explore using an AppKit alternative (QLPreviewPanel), but you’ll have to do some hacking to get it to work from a Catalyst app:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814132/1601849

Comment: can not add QLPreviewPanel for Mac catalyst. check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/qlpreviewpanel?language=objc. If any other solution than please help me

Comment: Done using 'QLPreviewController'. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! I thought there was a QuickLook for iOS, but couldn’t find QLPreviewController. Glad that works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave compatibility with OSX 10.5, you can do this check:

```
if UIDevice.current.systemName == "Mac OS X" {
   let version = Int (UIDevice.current.systemVersion.prefix (2)) ?? 10
   if version > 10 {
      self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:targetURL];
   } else {
      //do something
   }
} else {
   self.documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:targetURL];


}
```